# compatible applications for vmware thinapp

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, portable

compatible applications for vmware thinapp?
For windows 7 or xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every program is supposed to be compatible, with the exception of:

- Software that **installs** and/or **requires device drivers** to function, so for example scanning software for a specific HP scanner. Or NVidia applications...
- Software with **copy protection**, for example the latest Battlefield game that uses copy protection. This copy protection will prevent you from running games in VMware Thinapp.

Apart from software that uses any of those techniques you should be fine.

Comment: Is adobe master collection fine?

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure about the master collection, but i've tried the trial of the latest photoshop. That worked fine :)